# Implementing Hierarchical Model View Controller (HMVC)

Tags: codeigniter

After Installing the https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

and setting up my admin and site folders in modules.

I am getting this error messages:

Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php

I wonder how to fix it.

Comment: $application_folder = 'application/site';  with the above error  or  $application_folder = 'application/modules/site';
 with a new erorr 
Warning: require_once(C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\masterlinkci\application\modules\site\config/constants.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\masterlinkci\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 70

Comment: Please re edit your question by clicking on edit button below tags paste it in question

Answer (score 0):

On your main index.php make `$application_folder = 'application';` as your apppath and then set routes for your admin and site modules

Set your base url must

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/masterlinkci/';
```

route.php

Examples only

```
// lower case is best for your routes.php as shown here 

$route['default_controller'] = 'site/home/index/';

$route['admin'] = 'admin/cpages/index/';
$route['something'] = 'modulename/controller/function/';
```

> modules > site > controllers > Home.php

And

> modules > admin > controllers > Cpages.php

Not

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'modules/site/Home';
$route['home'] = 'modules/site/Home/';
$route['admin'] = 'modules/admin/Cpages/';
```

***Note: You may need a suitable htaccess file in main root directory***

Make sure you also follow the file and class naming way as said here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

[image]